# How do I enable mod_define under Debian 7

Tags: debian, apache2.2

I am running Debian 7 stable and would like to enable the Define directive on Apache 2.2 so that lines like this parse without error:

```
Define docroot /home/some/path/to/document/root
```

Answer (score -1):

This directive does not exist by default on Apache 2.2. You can either add the module manually:

http://people.apache.org/~rjung/mod_define/mod_define.html

or use environment variables with the syntax ${docroot}. On Debian, it is typically done in /etc/apache2/envvars:

export docroot=/home/some/path/to/document/root

Comment: The given link requires you to recompile entire Apache. That's not good solution.